# Why ASYNC AWAIT doesnt work well in use effect in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

im trying to get user location, and then use the location to return relevant data for is location.

but in the second function i get that the location is null (when i console.log(location) it prints the right location, at the second print, the first print is null) it seems like the second function is not waiting until the first one is done.

Here is some code:

**from the component**

```
    const location = useSelector(state => state.locationReducer.location);
    useEffect(()=> {
        (async () => {
            await getLocation();

            // here i'm using the location from the first function
            await getInfo(location);
        })()
    }, []);


    const getLocation = async() => {
        try {
            await dispatch(getLocation());
            console.log(location);
        } catch (err) {
            // TODO HANDLE ERROR;
            console.log('Err:', err);
        }
    }
```

**in the action**

```
export const getLocation = locationName => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const location = **await** locationService.getLocation(locationName);
            **await** dispatch(setLocation(location));
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        };
    };
};

const setLocation = location => {
    return {
        type: types.SET_LOCATION,
        location
    };
};
```

**in service**

```
async function getLocation(locationName) {
    try {]
        return **await** axios.get(`${url}/${locationName}`);
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    };
};
```

Comment: In your component did you tried to use `dispatch`? There is a `useDispatch` hook from witch you can get a dispatch instance and in the useEffect your actions need to be wrapped in a dispatch call like: `await dispatch(getLocation())`;

Comment: i am using dispatch, here is more from the component     ```const getLocation = async() => {
        try {
            await dispatch(getLocation());
            console.log(location);
        } catch (err) {
    
            console.log('Err:', err);
        }
    }```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `location` value from the selector won't update after your first function has run and before the second function, so there you'll see the old value in your `location` variable.

You might need to return your location value from the reducer:

```js
export const getLocation = locationName => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const location = await locationService.getLocation(locationName);
            await dispatch(setLocation(location));

            return location;
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        };
    };
};
```

And use the returned location in your `useEffect`:

```js
    useEffect(()=> {
        (async () => {
            const location = await getLocation();

            // here i'm using the location from the first function
            await getInfo(location);
        })()
    }, []);
```

Or another possibility, to have an another effect, wich depends son the location value:

```
    const location = useSelector(state => state.locationReducer.location);
    useEffect(()=> {
        getLocation();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=> {
      if(location) {
        getInfo(location);
      }
    }, [location]);
```

And this would run every time location changes, and location has some value.

Comment: Thank you! both are working! which one of this options is the best practice ?

Comment: It depends, I would say the second option is more idiomatic in a react-redux application, but in that case the second effect (with `getInfo`) would run every time the location changes, which might be good (because the the info would update if the location updates), but might be bad depending on your requirements for the logic of your component.

Comment: so, if i put the getLocation in App.js and the sec function - getInfo(location) in the component with useEffect that will re-render the component every time the location changes, is it idiomatic? or good practice?

Comment: It is idiomatic to react to changes like this, but if in your app, your requirement is that the getInfo must not be called just on the first render, then the first way is to go :)

Answer (score 1):

As Per Dan Abramov-

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchMyAPI() {
    let url = 'http://something';
    let config = {};
    const response = await myFetch(url);
    console.log(response);
  }  
  fetchMyAPI();
}, []);
```

Here is the link for reference - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326#issuecomment-441680293

Or You can simply use .then()

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    asyncCall().then(setVal);
  });
```

Article on how to fetch -  https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data